# How to connect UIPickerView options to individual pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

I just joined this site after looking very hard for an answer to my question and you guys seem to be amazing at what you do. I want to build a simple intro app for the iPhone. The problem I ran into is that I want to use a UIPickerView for choosing a variety of options, I have about 20 options in the pickerview. Next thing I want to do is to be able to open the next window when you click an option, I want to have individual windows for each of my options in the pickerview. Essentially I have a brand, then when you pick the brand by selecting it on the pickerview, you move on to the right accessories made for that brand. There are individual accessories made for each brand which is why I need a different new window for each. I already have my pickerview in place I just dont know how to proceed to the next step. Once I select an item on the pickerview by tapping, I want it to move to the corresponding next window. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that when declaring your UIPickerView, you've set the delegate to current view either in Interface Builder or done so in the code i.e. `myPicker.delegate = self;`. Also in your .h file, you have set up the controller such that it is analogous to `myViewController: UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate>`.

You'll implement the following method and use the `row` argument to decide which view to show next. This method gets fired after a row is selected (and was wired to do so the moment you specified which class is the delegate of the picker view). Assuming you're using a navigationController, it could look something like:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    //For example, you can do a switch based on the row
    switch (row) {
         case 0:
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:myFirstView animated:YES];
             break;
         case 1:
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:mySecondView  animated:YES];
             break;
         // ..
         // ..
         case 19:
             break;
         default:
        //...
    }
}
```

Note that if you declare a new variable (such as one of your view controllers) inside a case statement, you need braces `{ }` inside the case statement in order to do so.

Alternatively, if you don't want the event to fire automatically after a row is selected (for example, in case of the user accidentally selecting a row), you can create a button that the user presses to confirm the selection/proceed. Upon pressing the button, the button's target method could act according to the selected row in the picker.  You can find the selected row with the following method call `[myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]` (assuming your picker only has one column/"component").

Good luck!

**Edits (after reading your follow-up questions):**

Assuming that SingleComponentPickerViewController.h is the view where you created your UIPickerView.

**SingleComponentPickerViewController.h:**

```
@interface SingleComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

**SingleComponentPickerViewController.m:**

In your viewDidLoad, (or wherever you created the pickerview), set the delegate:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    //...
    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    //...
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

To access your myPickerView variable in the above method, it will mean that your UIPickerView object has class scope or is a property.

Also, have the action that is fired after the button press in this file.

```
-(void)onButtonPress:(id)sender {
    //This gets the currently selected row from the picker
    //Again, assuming you have your picker as a property or class variable
    int row = [myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

    //In your final version you need to use a condition to decide which view to show.
    if (row == 0) {
        AnotherView *anotherViewInstance = [[AnotherView alloc] init];

        //Show "anotherView"
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewInstance animated:YES];
    }
    else if (row == 1) {
        AnotherView2 *anotherView2 = [[AnotherView2 alloc] init];

        //Show "anotherView"
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherView2 animated:YES];
    }
    else if (row == 2) {
        AnotherView3 *anotherView3 = [[AnotherView3 alloc] init];

        //Show "anotherView"
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherView3 animated:YES];
    }
    //...continue with the rest of your conditions here
}
```

If you are using Interface Builder, then you should change the return type from `void` to `IBAction`.

**SingleComponentAppDelegate.m**

Right now I'm assuming your App Delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` looks something like this near the end:

```
//....
self.viewController = [[SingleComponentPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName...];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;     
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

You want to modify it the window's rootViewController property to be set to a navigation controller, with your custom view controller inside of it. This way, you can easily push and pop views onto the screen.

```
//...
//Create your base view, similar (or even identically) to what was done earlier
SingleComponentPickerViewController *myView = [[SingleComponentPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName...]; 

//Stick it inside a UINavigationController so you can push and pop views on top of it.
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];

//Assign that to the window's rootViewController, show it, and return
self.window.rootViewController = nav;     
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Comment: Hi eitan27, thank you so much for your response, I am very new to this and your post has helped me understand the underlying of the pickerview a bit better. I am just confused as to where I am supposed to add this stuff to. The Classes I have are: SingleComponentAppDelegate.m, SingleComponentAppDelegate.h, SingleComponentPickerViewController.h, SingleComponentPickerViewController.m, and a new view I created that opens if I press a button called AnotherView.h and AnotherView.m.

Comment: What you wrote is exactly what I want to do, I have the components in my PickerView and when I select one and press a button, it opens up a new page such as AnotherView, AnotherView1...to..AnotherView20,etc. Each of those views is made for each of my components in my PickerView. The following code is what I have for the button that I want to press but I don't know how to link that to the selected row which would be row 0 for that page. I tried adding the code you gave me but it said that navigationController is not defined. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much Eitan, I will follow your instructions and do my best to get it working. I am just trying to learn Objective-C although I have some experience in C++, this is somewhat different than what I did before in my programming classes. It has been a few years since I took those classes too. I appreciate all your help. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! If you get stuck, I'd suggest taking a few steps back and learning about Navigation Controllers - just look up basic tutorials. They are the simplest means of "pushing" and "popping" other views onto the screen.

Comment: Thank you Eitan. I also had another thing to ask if you have time or whenever you can check it out. I guided myself using the guide found on this link http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-select-component-from-uipickerview-and-display-the-next-screen/    That is pretty much all I have. The only thing I want to change is the fact that no matter what you choose in your picker, it opens up the same window no matter what. I wanted to modify that so that I can open up individual pages for each pickerview option instead but after many weeks I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I also read a lot of the Apple Documentation for developers to learn as much as possible about Objective-C but even after everything I've read, I can't figure it out. I just want to make this app as an entry level way for me to learn objective-C. I feel like I'm light years behind you but I want to get better at it. I'm sure you must be extremely busy so I understand if you don't have time. Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: I updated the onButtonPress method.  If you have 20 different view controllers, then you need to make sure that you've actually added those classes to the project and implemented them. In one of your earlier comments, you said you only had the AppDelegate, AnotherView, SingleComponentPickerViewController.  In my example, I assumed you had a few others - AnotherView2, AnotherView3, and so on.  Finally, I'm not a fan of that tutorial because it assumes a lot of knowledge and doesn't explain things well.  I suggest going to the iTunes and downloading free Stanford Lectures itunes.stanford.edu/

Comment: I agree, it was very hard trying to follow the tutorial and I was lost most of the time. I downloaded the Stanford Lectures from iTunes and I will start from scratch again and follow your directions instead of trying to figure out the steps in that tutorial. Thank you very much for your great advise Eitan and for your time specially.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`UIPickerViewDelegate` Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```